# Cancelled unused Russian tourist visa

Tags: visas, us-citizens, russia, visa-cancellation

Until recently I have travelled to Russia frequently - on regular tourist visas in my USA passport. The last time I travelled, the Embassy issued my visa for wrong dates (in my application I requested dates 5-15 October, but they issued it for 5-15 November the same year).  I notified them of the mistake and they issued a new visa for the right dates and cancelled the first one - i.e. there's a stamp now on the old visa stating "Cancelled without prejudice".

How should I report this cancelled visa when I apply for a Russian visa next time? Specifically, there's a question on the application form, "Have you ever had Russian visa cancelled or revoked?"

**EDIT:** To clarify, I am not asking *whether* to report this cancellation, but rather *how* to report it.

Comment: I'd appreciate a reason for the downvote.

Comment: Ok, two downvotes without any reason... Interesting...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Specifically, there's a question on the application form, "Have you ever had Russian visa cancelled or revoked?"

Well, have you?

You have, so you should choose the "yes" option. When I filled an application for a Russian visa a few months ago, all yes/no questions where you might need or want to provide additional information about your answer offered a text field to do so (this wouldn't appear until selecting "yes" to the question). I can't guarantee that this particular question offers such a field but I'd be very surprised if not. Write in that field a short explanation like the one in this question. A previous visa being cancelled because they got the dates wrong and issued you a replacement with the correct dates won't negatively affect your chances of getting a visa now.

Even if there's no such field for you to explain the circumstances, you should still select yes. Lying on visa application forms is a great way to find yourself permanently banned from visiting a country, especially when it relates to documents issued by the country you're applying to.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. At no time did I even think about hiding this fact.  The question was about "how", not "whether" to report it.

Answer (score 0):

They issue your visa wrong, it's not your fault. Next time that you apply again just tell them what's happen. Or may you can ask a paperwork about that mistake to show in the embassy next time.

Comment: I do not know why this is downvoted, but it is the right thing to do. Note: the visa was not cancelled, but just rectified (the original was just wrong). On original wrong visa, you could had having problems, because the visa does not agree with your Russia invitation and your application. The "cancelled visa" were never been valid.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I'm not the downvoter, but I have to disagree with you saying it wasn't cancelled. It might not have been valid, but it was issued and then they put a stamp saying "cancelled without prejudice" on it. We clearly agree that this isn't anything OP needs to be worried about. But if you'd like to explain to the Russian embassy how getting a replacement visa issued due to a mistake didn't involve the initial (wrong, but nevertheless issued) visa being cancelled, even when it's still in your passport with a big stamp declaring it "cancelled", you're braver than I.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi it's not entirely implausible that they might consider the erroneous (immediately cancelled and replaced) visa not to have been issued, but I certainly wouldn't declare that it "was not cancelled" or advise anybody to proceed under that assumption without an *extremely* good reason to believe that's Russian policy for how to treat this sort of correction.